# Convergence of Recurrence Relation problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

The two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are defined by
$$a_1=0, \ \ b_1=1$$
$$ \begin{cases} 
     a_{n+1} &= a_{n}-\frac{b_n}{n+1} \\
     b_{n+1} &= na_{n}-b_n
   \end{cases}\ ,\   n\in\mathbb{N}
$$
I want to show that both $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converge to $0$.
At first, I tried to see if one sequence is increasing and another one is decreasing, and both are bounded then I can use the monotone convergence theorem, but after computing the first few terms, I figured out that $b_n$ is not monotonic.

Next, I observed that $a_n=a_1-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{b_k}{k+1}$. However, when I tried to obtain similar result for $b_n$, I get some strange result, which is
$$b_n=na_n-(n-1)a_{n-1}+(n-2)a_{n-2}-\cdots+(-1)^na_1+(-1)^{n+1}b_1$$
And it seems not useful to conclude that both sequences will converge to $0$.So
I wonder if there is any better way to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

This is a linear recurrence so it can be represented as

$$
R_{n+1}=M_n R_n
$$

Here $M_n = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -\frac{1}{n+1} \\
 n & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$  with eigenvalues $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ and $|\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}|<1$ for $n > 0$

You can also use the characteristic functions for $a_n, b_n$ to solve this:

$$
\cases{
\sum_{k=0}^n\left((k+1)a_{k+1}x^k-k a_k x^k - a_k x^k + b_k x^k\right) = 0\\
\sum_{k=0}^n\left(b_{k+1}x^k-k a_kx^k + b_k x^k\right) = 0}
$$

now calling

$$
A(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k\\
B(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k\\
$$

we have

$$
\cases{
A'(x)-x A'(x)-A(x)+B(x) = 0\\
\frac 1x \left(B(x)-b_0\right) -x A'(x)+B(x) = 0
}
$$

etc.

Comment: Do you have any idea without using eigenvalues? Coz I haven't learned yet

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: It is easy to get
$$a_{n+2} = \frac{1}{n+2}(a_{n+1} + a_n), \ n\ge 1 \tag{1}$$
and
$$b_{n+2} = \frac{1}{n}(b_{n+1} + b_n), \ n\ge 1. \tag{2}$$

Then use strong mathematical induction to prove that $|a_n| \le \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Then prove that $a_n = b_{n+2}, n\ge 1$.